# Keyboard Indicator for Layouts with the Same Country Code

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, indicator, keyboard-layout

There appears to be no way to remove the keyboard indicator when multiple keyboard layouts are used in newer ubuntu releases.  I have started using Ian Scott's flag icons found [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php) to save space in the indicator area. The problem is both of my keyboard layouts (standard USA and USA Dvorak) have the same country code so that the indicator does not indicate which layout I have selected.

Is there any way for the keyboard indicator to use different icons for Layouts with the same country code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can't answer your question and you're probably aware of what I'm going to tell you.

However, to work around this in the meantime, why not install the Dvorak one under a different country code? That's what I did. At least I can quickly see which keyboard is active.

Comment: Great idea snth! That had not occurred to me. Its the best workaround so far. Now just need some country abbreviated as DV or DK or the like.